# Scraping a table Including hyperlinks and upload it to google sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a table and keep any hyperlinks included then upload the result to a google sheet
I have finished the first part using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
# Define URL
url = 'https://www.marefa.org/%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%85%D8%A9_%D8%A3%D9%81%D8%B6%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9'# Ask hosting server to fetch url
requests.get(url)
response=requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
#If the output is <Response [200]> so that means the server allows us to collect 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
indiatable=soup.find('table',{'class':"wikitable"})


df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable))
# convert list to dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
df.head()
#df.to_excel("hi2.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

Can anyone give me some hint on how to finish the rest of the task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to write hyperlinks in a way that Sheets will recognize them as hyperlinks, but the following will create extra columns to hold the links:

```py
indiatable_headers = [col for cols in [
    [chead, chead+' [link]'] for chead in [
        c.get_text(strip=True) for c in 
        indiatable.select_one('tr:has(th)').select('th')
]] for col in cols]
# indiatable_headers = ['الترتيب', 'الترتيب [link]', 'الاسم', 'الاسم [link]', 'المؤلف', 'المؤلف [link]', 'البلد', 'البلد [link]', 'الرواية', 'الرواية [link]']

indiatable_data = [[col for cols in [[
        c.get_text(strip=True) if c.text.strip() else (
            c.img.get('alt', '') if c.find('img') else ''
        ), 'https://www.marefa.org'+c.a.get('href') if c.find('a') else None
    ] for c in r.select('td')
] for col in cols] for r in indiatable.select('tr') if not r.find('th')]
# no text --> looks for image with alt attribute

indiadf = pandas.DataFrame(
    indiatable_data, columns=indiatable_headers
).dropna(axis='columns', how='all').set_index(indiatable_headers[0])
# drops empty columns [ie, '[link]' cols with no links], and set first column as index
```

After that, you can create a spreadsheet with `indiadf.to_excel` (DON'T use `index=False` this time unless you want to lose the `الترتيب` column, since that has now been set as the index), and then manually upload it...

---

If you want to automate the google sheets part as well, you can look into [the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and maybe modules like [pydrive](https://medium.com/@annissouames99/how-to-upload-files-automatically-to-drive-with-python-ee19bb13dda) or [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets).